# What value should be for (id = auto-increment) the POST method in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I use package mysql for NodeJs to Post Data to MySqlDB
this is my code example:

```
app.post('/countries', (req, res) => {
    const country = req.body.country;
    const city = req.body.city;
    const town = req.body.town;

    con.query('insert into countries value(?, ?, ?)', [Canada, Toronto, Mississauga]
})
```

I have an Error because I did't insert ID VALUE, what value should I put in POST if inside MySql id = auto-increment? thank you =)

I did'n find the idea to resolve this proplem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert is missing the column names, so it is assuming all columns.  It is always better to be explicit, so adding a column does not break your code:

```
insert into countries (country, city, town) values (?, ?, ?)
```

and there is no need to include the auto-increment column.

If for some reason you do need to include the id column, you can just specify the value as null (null in the literal sql, not a "null" string).